# Bash script arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

Im trying to pass arguments to a script i wrote, but cant get it right.

What i want is one mandatory argument without a flag, and two optional arguments with flags, so it can be called like this:

```
./myscript mandatory_arg -b opt_arg -a opt_arg
```

or

```
./myscript mandatory_arg -a opt_arg
./myscript mandatory_arg -b opt_arg
```

I looked into getopts and got this:

```
while getopts b:a: option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

if "$1" = ""; then
    exit
fi

echo "$1"
echo "$MERGE_BRANCH"
echo "$ACTION"
```

But it does not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your *mandatory argument* appears **last**, then you should try the following code: *[comments inline]*

```
OPTIND=1
while getopts "b:a:" option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

# reset positional arguments to include only those that have not
# been parsed by getopts

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift

# test: there is at least one more argument left

(( 1 <= ${#} )) || { echo "missing mandatory argument" 2>&1 ; exit 1; };

echo "$1"
echo "$MERGE_BRANCH"
echo "$ACTION"
```

The result:

```
~$ ./test.sh -b B -a A test
test
B
A
~$ ./tes.sh -b B -a A
missing mandatory argument
```

---

If you really want the *mandatory argument* to appear **first**, then you can do the following thing:

```
MANDATORY="${1}"
[[ "${MANDATORY}" =~ -.* ]] && { echo "missing or invalid mandatory argument" 2>&1; exit 1; };

shift # or, instead of using `shift`, you can set OPTIND=2 in the next line   
OPTIND=1
while getopts "b:a:" option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
        b) MERGE_BRANCH=${OPTARG};;
        a) ACTION=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

# reset positional arguments to include only those that have not
# been parsed by getopts

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift

echo "$MANDATORY"
echo "$MERGE_BRANCH"
echo "$ACTION"
```

The result is the following:

```
~$ ./test.sh test -b B -a A
test
B
A
~$ ./tes.sh -b B -a A
missing or invalid mandatory argument
```

Comment: When trying to run this it prints out the mandatory argument and then "" for the optionals, if i run without the mandatory it replies with "missing mandatory argument"

Comment: What is the reason for not recommending having the mandatory argument first? and i think something is missing from the last edit

Comment: @A.Jac it's just a matter of *convention* and *personal taste*

Comment: @A.Jac Assume that your *mandatory argument* is the name of a file, and that your file name is `-test`, with the former code you can write `./test..sh -b B -a A -- -test` and have your program work correctly, whereas with the last code you won't be able to parse it: `--` is used to make `getopt` stop looking for *options*, but A) `-b B -a A` won't be recognized as options B) `--` will fail the test `[[ ${MANDATORY} =~ -.* ]]`

Comment: Anyway I removed my personal opinions from the answer, because clearly there are *workarounds* for the issues I see with this approach, it is only a matter of implementing them with some more extra code.